# Не совершается покупка в магазине

Tags: php, mysql, update

Я сделал магазин на популярных языках программирования, довольно простой- Вывод списка товаров, сам товар является ссылкой на покупку, ссылка ведет на исполнительный файл, а там происходит сама покупка. Сразу скажу магазин полностью виртуален- и предметы в нём, и валюта - кварки, никак не связаны с реальными деньгами

При покупке пишется Покупка успешно совершена, хотя счет никак не изменяется.

Код файла:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
    </head>
<body>
<?
    if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
        $id = $_GET["id"];
    }  else {}

    if (isset($_GET["us_id"])) { 
        $us_id = $_GET["us_id"];
    } else {}

    include_once'db.php';
    include_once'handler.php';

    $prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");
    if ($sql) {
        echo'Вы успешно совершили покупку!';
    } else {
        echo'Произошла ошибка';
    }
?>
</body>
```

Пожалуйста подскажите где я спотыкнулся, и возможное решение проблемы

Comment: `Я сделал магазин на популярных языках программирования` улыбнуло)))

Comment: Не уверен что в `".$prod['price']."` что-то есть, проверьте свой запрос: `var_dump("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");` и нам сюда результат

Comment: string(61) "UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck - WHERE user_id = " Произошла ошибка

Comment: Ну вот видите, все плохо. ПЕРЕД `$sql = ...` напишите `var_dump($prod); exit;` нам сюда результат (лучше в вопрос) и мы вам поможем.

Comment: Не понял, честно говоря

Comment: тоесть вместо запроса?

Comment: var_dump($prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");)

Comment: `$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");` замените на `$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'"); var_dump($prod); exit;` запустите и результат покажите нам

Comment: `resource(8) of type (mysql result) `

Comment: у вас или не приходит id товара, или по этому id нет товара в таблице  red_shop или price этого товара null

Comment: @madfan41k нене, фишка в том что `mysql_query` не возвращает массив.

Comment: И как это исправить?

Comment: $us_id соответствует id пользователя? Проверяли?

Comment: соответствует. проверил

Comment: Попробуйте вывести id и us_id, если выведет - проблема в запросе.

Comment: echo $id." ".$us_id;

Comment: написало это `1us_id=37` хотя должно написать 1 37

Comment: Потому что вы присвоили значение с урла.

Comment: Никита, объявите переменные самостоятельно и выполните запрос.

Comment: Вы неправильно создали ссылку с GET запросом, чтобы разделить несколько значений используется знак &, я сразу не увидел Вашей ссылки, извините

Comment: Держите правильную ссылку: echo '<a href="?id='.$id.'&us_id='.$user_id.'">КУПИТЬ</a>';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");
```

меняем на:

```
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");
$prod = mysql_fetch_array($prod);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");
```

Comment: Не помогло, написало Произошла ошибка

Comment: `$prod = mysql_fetch_array($prod);` замените на `$prod = mysql_fetch_array($prod); var_dump($prod); exit;` и покажите результат.

Comment: array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "100" ["price"]=> string(3) "100" }

Comment: @НикитаЧереп все правильно, с первым запросом разобрались. значит теперь проблема со вторым, и скорее всего с вашими параметрами. Возвращаемся к началу диалога: `var_dump("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");` и результат сюда (После $prod).

Comment: string(64) "UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -100 WHERE user_id = " Произошла ошибка

Comment: @НикитаЧереп У вас отсутствует `$us_id`. видимо отсутствует $_GET["us_id"]

Comment: Да нет, присутствует `$sql = var_dump("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");`

Comment: Вот полный `<?
if(isset($_GET["id"]))
{$id = $_GET["id"];}
else{}
if(isset($_GET["us_id"]))
{$us_id = $_GET["us_id"];}
else{}
include_once'db.php';
include_once'handler.php';
$prod = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM red_shop WHERE id = '$id'");
$prod = mysql_fetch_array($prod);
$sql = var_dump("UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -".$prod['price']." WHERE user_id = ".$us_id." ");
if ($sql) {echo'Вы успешно совершили покупку!';} else {echo'Произошла ошибка';}
    ?>`

Comment: @НикитаЧереп У вас условие `if (isset($_GET["us_id"])) {` не выполняется `$us_id` - пустое. Урл какой у вас?

Comment: ссылка ведет сюда: `<a href="sel.php?id='.$prod['id'].'us_id='.$user['user_id'].'">КУПИТЬ</a> ` a url - sel.php?id=1us_id=37

Comment: @НикитаЧереп а должно быть `<a href="sel.php?id='.$prod['id'].'&us_id='.$user['user_id'].'">КУПИТЬ</a>` исправляйте

Comment: исправил, теперь `string(64) "UPDATE users_profiles SET quarck = quarck -100 WHERE user_id = " Произошла ошибка`

Comment: @НикитаЧереп урл какой?

Comment: sel.php?id=1us_id=37

Comment: @НикитаЧереп а должен быть `sel.php?id=1&us_id=37` -.- на кнопку надо было еще раз нажать. Вы забываете между 2 переменными знак `&`

Comment: Теперь вот так: sel.php?id=1&us_id=37

Comment: @НикитаЧереп хорошо, и что? какие результаты? все нормально?

Comment: Ураа, заработало! Спасибо вам!

Comment: Хорошо, покупка выполнена и счет изменился

Comment: Теперь бы сделать цикл проверки, типо Если результат <=0 то отменить покупку и вывести ошибку

Comment: @НикитаЧереп ну это уже другой вопрос, если не знаете как опишите подробно что надо и пример кода, попробуем вам помочь.

Comment: здрасте, а у вас вк есть?

Comment: @НикитаЧереп -.- есть

Comment: а можно ли вас в добавить в друзья? Просто иногда когда оставляю вопросы, мне начинают говорить тип выкинь ты эт php, щас модный тот иль другой, а вы как я вижу разбираетесь

Comment: @НикитаЧереп скайп такой-же как и логин.